# IIS URL Rewrite - IIS 7.5

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7, iis-7.5

I'm trying to achieve a certain directory structure with my IIS hosted web apis. The requirements are as follows:

1. All applications should include "/vas/" in their URL, e.g:

> http://example.com/vas/webapi1
>
> http://example.com/vas/webapi2

2. On the /vas/ root itself there should also be a web api, which is hit only when there is *no valid sub application*, e.g this request should be routed to a controller in the "base" web api application:

> http://example.com/vas/controller/action/id=123

But this request, given that there is a web api called "webapi1" should be routed as normal:

> http://example.com/vas/webapi1/controller/action/id=321

So the challenge is to have a rule where all incoming requests starting with /vas/ but that *does not point to a valid application or web api* should be routed to the web api running on the base url.

I have installed the URL Rewrite module for IIS 7.5 and tried different approaches, but my URL Rewrite reg ex'es don't do as I want. Having all requests routed to the "base" application is no problem, but when I add a condition it seems like all routing stops working. I have successfully used rewriting previously for simpler tasks, but never with a structure like this. I am not sure if the best approach is to have the root application running as "/vas" in IIS and then create nested sub applications below or if it's better to have a simple virtual directory with a completely different name and just use some sort of rewrite / re-routing.

I was hoping to get this working on the local IIS instead of asking the network administrators to handle it in the load balancer.

Comment: It is simply too difficult for IIS URL Rewrite module to know your application's logic and you should do so inside your web app using technology such as ASP.NET routing.

Comment: It doesn't really have to know the logic, if I had a rule that could say "if the request url does NOT start with "/vas/[someprefix]" then send it to the base app. I could then make sure all my sub applications were named with this prefix, and the routing should work..

Comment: @LexLi: I went with your suggestion and implemented some simple logic in my app. I would have still preferred a reg ex in IIS, but for now this works. Thanks!